# Order SQL statement by count of sub-records efficiently (MS-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a table with two columns, an ID and a serial number. Let's call this table `vehicle`. The serial numbers are used for an auto-complete textbox. Right now, I simply narrow the list with a contains/like statement and select the top 5 hits. Obviously, this returns the 5 oldest records.

These vehicle entries are referenced by another table via foreign key. Let's call that one `appearence`. To improve the user experience, I want to present the five vehicles, which appeared most often during the last three months.

A simple approach would be, to simply join the two tables together, group by the serial number, count the number of appearences in the specified time range, and finally order it by that count descending.

The problem is, that this auto-complete textbox is accessed relatively often, so I wonder, if there is a built in optimization for this. My first idea was, to create a daily job, which updated a new `probability` column and order by that column. I've also seen the statistics option in SQL Server Management Studio, and I wonder, if that could help me. Or would there be a way to use views for that?

Updating the order every day would be abundant.

Here's the select statement (without the time component yet):

```
SELECT RegistrationNumber, count(lbt.ID) as cnt
  FROM [Trailer] t
  INNER JOIN [LoadingBay_Trailer] lbt ON t.ID = lbt.ID_Trailer
  group by t.RegistrationNumber
  order by cnt desc
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide us with sample data and expected results? Please don't use an image - we need the actual data...

Comment: Is just querying the table too slow? As it sits currently this question is not answerable because it lacks any kind of detail.

Comment: See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips and tools to add the necessary detail to this question.

Comment: @Birel I've edited my post and added the SQL statement.

Comment: @SeanLange It's not slow. But it creates a load on the (shared) server. And the software has many users.

Comment: Every query creates a load on the server. You seem to be trying to solve a performance issue that doesn't exist. Keep in mind that a view is just a stored query, it still executes the query every single time.

Comment: @SeanLange That's the reason, why I was asking for a solution, where I dont't have to join together two tables and iterate over thousands of datasets every time someone strokes a key. Pre-calculating the order once per day would be sufficient enough. I just want to know, if there *is* a more elegant solution, than to simply add a new column and fill it every day by an automated job.

Comment: Possibly there is a better solution. But you are quickly approaching an anti-pattern known as premature optimization. This is when you come up with a non-standard design to solve a performance issue that doesn't exist because you suspect there might be one. Given your explanation I don't see how you can avoid querying the data. But you can use the cache to help minimize the amount of queries you need to run.

Comment: @SeanLange The only thing I see is, that the load on our servers is increasing, because more and more applications are being made. Therefore we shall try to avoid costy queries whenever they can be avoided. And I don't see any advantage in running this redundant query on (actually) every keystroke someone makes in that specific textfield.

Comment: OK. As I said you could utilize caching to help minimize the number of queries that you have to execute. But no matter how you slice it you have to look at a refined set of data on each keystroke. With no actual details of what you are doing it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: @SeanLange I have one table `Trailer` containing truck trailers with their registration number. `LoadingBay_Trailer` contains, from when to when a trailer was docked to a loading bay. The autocomplete appears in the UI, where you can register a trailer to a loading bay. The user enters some characters of the registration plate and as soon as he entered at least two, I call the database. I want to present him the top 5 possible trailers according to his entry, and the count of dockings during the last 3 months. It's unlikely that a trailer appears twice per day, so caching would be totally fine

Comment: A top 5 query on a table with proper indexing should be so fast you wouldn't even notice a performance hit on the server unless there are hundreds of thousand of executions per second. I would suggest doing this with a standard query initially and get the proper indexing in place. This should be fast like lightning. Then **IF** there are performance problems and the can't be addressed through standard optimization techniques start looking for "out of the box" type solutions like storing data daily and such.

Comment: @SeanLange The top five is performed only after sorting. I will post an answer with my current solution.

Comment: Well of course top 5 is after sorting. That is how you define top 5.

Comment: @SeanLange I've added the code of my view below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I've solved the problem with a simple view. I don't like this approach, because it creates a lot of load on the server, as the view is called after every keystroke the user performs:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TrailerAutocompleteHelper] AS
SELECT
    t.ID,
    t.RegistrationNumber,
    t.InUse,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT_BIG(lbt.ID_Trailer) DESC, RegistrationNumber ASC) AS Probability
FROM [dbo].[AvailableTrailers] t
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LoadingBay_Trailer] lbt ON
    t.ID = lbt.ID_Trailer AND
    lbt.Arrival > DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())
GROUP BY t.ID, t.RegistrationNumber, t.InUse
GO
```

And C#

```
public async Task<List<TrailerAutocomplete>> GetTrailers(string registrationNumberPart) {
    return await mapi.db.TrailerAutocompleteHelpers
        .Where(t => t.RegistrationNumber.Contains(registrationNumberPart))
        .OrderBy(t => t.Probability)
        .Select(t => new TrailerAutocomplete() {
            ID = t.ID,
            RegistrationNumber = t.RegistrationNumber,
            InUse = t.InUse
        })
        .Take(10)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

And here's what Entity framework makes out of my command:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Project1].[RegistrationNumber] AS [RegistrationNumber], 
    [Project1].[InUse] AS [InUse]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent1].[RegistrationNumber] AS [RegistrationNumber], 
        [Extent1].[InUse] AS [InUse], 
        [Extent1].[Probability] AS [Probability]
        FROM (SELECT 
    [TrailerAutocompleteHelper].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [TrailerAutocompleteHelper].[RegistrationNumber] AS [RegistrationNumber], 
    [TrailerAutocompleteHelper].[InUse] AS [InUse], 
    [TrailerAutocompleteHelper].[Probability] AS [Probability]
    FROM [dbo].[TrailerAutocompleteHelper] AS [TrailerAutocompleteHelper]) AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[RegistrationNumber] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N''~''
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Probability] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'%ABC%'
```

Comment: Add a TOP 5 to this to limit the number of results returned. You will need an order by here to ensure you get the correct 5. This should be crazy fast if you have proper indexing in place.

Comment: @SeanLange I've added my server side code as well. It's actually top 10 ^^

Comment: I noticed it was 10. Put that in your view to limit the amount of data being sent back. The load on your server here is because you are sending everything back from the database and then throwing most of the data away. Limit the amount of rows at the source.

Comment: @SeanLange Not exactly. Entity Framework actually creates a statement, which limits the number of results through the `Take` command.

Comment: Gosh the code that EF generates is just horrific. And the performance here is going to be brutal to say the least because it has a leading wildcard on your like predicate. That is going to kill your performance and your server. Can you change that to remove the leading wildcard?

Comment: Also, you are still querying the entire result set with your view. Add top to your view and help yourself. The query engine doesn't need every row if you only want 10.

Comment: @SeanLange The `RegistrationNumber` column is an `NCHAR(9)`. The leading wildcard is required, because the users should be able to input any part of the registration number, not just from the beginning. So if the number is "B-AB123H", and the user enters 123, it should find it anyways.

Comment: @SeanLange Just, that you don't get me wrong. The query *should* return up to ten results, no matter which rrgistration number part you enter. If I would limit the view to 10 results, wouldn't it just return the top 10 most seen trailers, no matter which registration number you would enter?

Comment: Well then a standard query is going to be impossible to use. That pattern is nonSARGable and any indexes you put on the table will be useless. You need to look into full text indexing instead. Then you can either use full text searching or create an indexed view. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I thought you were using the view to get 10 rows but with your latest query I see it is a little different. ;)